# Cannot see the content of the volume from my Mac

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file

```
dataonly:
  image: busybox
  volumes:
    - /Users/xxx/work/personal/data-only/mongo:/data
  command: "true"

mongo:
  image: tutum/mongodb
  volumes_from:
    - dataonly
  environment:
    - AUTH=no
    - JOURNALING=yes
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
    - "28018:28018"
```

When I run docker-compose with this configuration, I can see the folder `/Users/xxx/work/personal/data-only/mongo/db` is created on my Mac but it's empty.

If I go in the `mongo` container and check the contents of the `/data/db` folder I can see all the mongodb related files there.

If I do `touch testfile` in `/data/db` folder in the mongo container, file doesn't appear on my Mac but if I do `touch testfile` in `/data` folder in the container I can see the file on my Mac in `/Users/xxx/work/personal/data-only/mongo`.

Comment: It sounds like the `volumes_from` might be using an older container to get the volumes.  If you run `docker-compose rm` and then run `up` again, does it fix the problem?

Comment: I did `docker-compose rm` couple of times but nothing changes.